# Python - Tree Insert Node

Tags: python, tree

Below is my code. I can't figure out what's wrong with my insert function. From the tests I'm running, it doesn't look like my tree is inserting new nodes. Can anyone point me in the right direction? 
When I run a test, for example, the height of tree should be 2 but output is 3. but I'm almost certain the length function is right.

```
class MyTree():
    def __init__(self, data):
        # Initialize this node, and store data in it
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.height = 0
        self.descendents = 0

    def getLeft(self):
        # Return the left child of this node, or None
        return self.left

    def getRight(self):
        # Return the right child of this node, or None
        return self.right

    def getData(self):
        # Return the data contained in this node
        return self.data

    def insert(self, data):
        if self.left == None:
            self.left = MyTree(data)
            self.descendents=1
        elif self.right == None:
            self.descendents=2
            self.right = MyTree(data)
        else :
            self.left.insert(data)
        return self


    def getHeight(self):
        # Return the height of this node

        if self.left==None:
                leftheight=0
        else:
            leftheight=self.left.getHeight() 

        if self.right==None:
            rightheight=0
        else:
            rightheight=self.right.getHeight()

        if self.left==None and self.right==None:
            return 0   
        h=max(leftheight, rightheight) + 1;
        self.height=h
        return h
```

Below is the test:

```
def Test(lib, seed=0, size=10, rounds=10, verbose=False):
random.seed(a=seed)

# Test MyTree

n = random.randint(0, size)
try:
    tree = lib.MyTree(n)
except:
    if verbose:
        print("Error: MyTree not creatable")
    return False


h=1
c=2
for i in range(1,size):
    n = random.randint(n,n*2)
    try:
        tree = tree.insert(n)

        #print(tree)
    except:
      #  print(c)
        if verbose:
            print("Error: Tree not insertable")
        return False

    tH = tree.getHeight()
    if CheckHeight(tree) != tH:
        if verbose:
            print("Error: Tree height calculation incorrect")
        return False

    if tH != h:
        if verbose:
            print("Error: Tree height incorrect: Should be {h} but is {tH}")
            print("should be:")

            print(h)
            print("is:")
            print(tH)
        return False

    if i == c:
        h+=1
        c+=(2**h)

del(tree)
if verbose:
    print("Tree test complete.")
# Tree works
yield  True
```

Comment: Where's the code you used to create and test your tree?

Comment: This design is a bit unusual--it seems to conflate Tree and Node classes into one. But the stranger thing is that the `insert` function only traverses left when the current node is full, so what we have is basically a linked list. It looks like it should insert nodes, though, so a [mcve] is necessary. Thanks.

Comment: @JayMody included tester below code